# SAP HANA "take over" option grayed out

Tags: hana

After opening a Calculation View, SAP HANA Studio sometimes shows the warning "The object is currently opened in read-only mode. Object belongs to multiple workspaces ..."

[image]

If you need to modify the Calculation View it is often possible to take over ownership via a button. But unfortunately this time it is grayed out.

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Work-around / fix:**

- Check out the file / folder
- Edit in Project Explorer view
- Activate in Project Explorer view